# Acessar método usando Traço (-) na URL CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Tenho um método de assinatura: `public function mostPopular()` estou tentando acessa-lo via `URL` da seguinte forma: `products/most-popular` porém estou sendo direcionado para uma página de Erro:

> The action most-popular is not defined in ProductsController

porém seguindo as convenções de nomes do CakePHP 3.0 não deveria acontecer este erro.

**Arquivo de rotas (routes.php)**

```
<?php

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

/**
 * The default class to use for all routes
 *
 * The following route classes are supplied with CakePHP and are appropriate
 * to set as the default:
 *
 * - Route
 * - InflectedRoute
 * - DashedRoute
 *
 * If no call is made to `Router::defaultRouteClass`, the class used is
 * `Route` (`Cake\Routing\Route\Route`)
 *
 * Note that `Route` does not do any inflections on URLs which will result in
 * inconsistently cased URLs when used with `:plugin`, `:controller` and
 * `:action` markers.
 *
 */
Router::defaultRouteClass('Route');

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    /**
     * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to a controller called 'Pages',
     * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
     * to use (in this case, src/Template/Pages/home.ctp)...
     */
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    // tendo pages após o dominio (sequido de qualquer coisa) será redirecionado para o controller pages,
    // método display, qualquer coisa após o * será passado como parametro
    /**
     * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
     */
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    /**
     * Connect catchall routes for all controllers.
     *
     * Using the argument `InflectedRoute`, the `fallbacks` method is a shortcut for
     *    `$routes->connect('/:controller', ['action' => 'index'], ['routeClass' => 'InflectedRoute']);`
     *    `$routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', [], ['routeClass' => 'InflectedRoute']);`
     *
     * Any route class can be used with this method, such as:
     * - DashedRoute
     * - InflectedRoute
     * - Route
     * - Or your own route class
     *
     * You can remove these routes once you've connected the
     * routes you want in your application.
     */
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
Plugin::routes();
```

**Código do método mostPopular():**

```
public function mostPopular()
{
    $this->layout = false;
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $productsQuantity = 4;
        $order = 'DESC';
        $column = 'visited';
        $subCategoryId = $this->request->data['subCategory'];
        $productsMostPopular = $this->Search->listProductsByTrend($subCategoryId, $productsQuantity, $column, $order);
        //$this->set('productsMostPopular', $productsMostPopular);
        //$this->set('_serialize',array('productsMostPopular'));
        echo json_encode($subCategoryId);
    }
}
```

**OBS: Estou usando o CakePHP 3.0**

Comment: Se não me engano você  não vai conseguir acessar o método dessa forma, somente conseguirá acessar se for nomeDoMetodo

Comment: @AndréBaill o problema é que segundo a documentação da forma que fiz está suportado pelo CakePHP

Comment: Puts, o Laravel por padrão vem com essa conversão :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters por padrão o Cake também tem

Comment: Acho que no cakephp 2 não era assim :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o CakePHP 3 mudou muita coisa

Comment: @Ricardo pode partilhar o link da doc onde viu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer com que o `CakePHP 3` usa-se o comportamento Default de rotas tracejadas mudando o paramentro do método `fallbacks` para `'DashedRoute'` por padrão as rotas vem com `$routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');`

```
$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
```